# Websphere web server slowing my outputstream response

Tags: streaming, websphere

I have been asked to look at a previous project which sends a pdf back to the browser by means of the outputstream of the servlet. With no web server (virtual host) in front of the response, we get the pdf in the browser in about 2 seconds. However, when we go through the web server it slows down to about 14 seconds. We have tried many solutions but we believe that the web server is holding onto the response before relaying it to the browser. Is there a flag which will allow for data to be streamed to the browser through the web server? Sorry I'm quite new to configuring WebSphere. We are using WebSphere 6.1.

Comment: We are using the default IBM HTTP server ( IBM_HTTP_Server/6.1.0.43 Apache/2.0.47 (Unix) DAV/2)

Answer (score 1):

IBM HTTP Server got an optimization called chunk size
Its noted that for large responses, small chunk size might hurt performance.

Read about this a little more here: [Web server plug-in request and response optimization properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/info/zseries/ae/uwsv_plugin_props1.html)

I think this is what you are looking for.

Regardless, if that PDF is static and not generated you might want to consider providing it as static file using the web server instead of taking it from WAS.

Comment: Hi Aviram, thanks very much for the suggestion. We increased the chunk size from 64k to 256k, but since the pdf being sent is only 6k it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I had the impression the PDF much bigger, I'll try to think of something else

Comment: Can you give more details about the request (GET/POST, big/small)  ? maybe the request is delayed and not the response. also check the logs when does WebSphere gets the request if its delayed or not